# Force Entity Framework Code First to Recreate Db that is deleted while application is running

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am currently developing a Web Api project that uses a MySQL backend database for querying.  The db access is performed using EF v6.1.3.

What I am trying to achieve is that if my backend database is deleted during the application running, that when the next request for a DB query comes in, the database is recreated to the latest migration and any seeding data inserted.

At the moment when i delete the database as the application is running the next request gets an open db connection error.

**Note:** The database is being deleted within Toad or MySQL Workbench.

If i subsequently recycle the application pool and then retry the request the backend database is created automatically.

Any help in this area would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

before you delete/drop the database you have to close all connections:

use the following command and then drop it:

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"  
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST');  
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
       { 
         $process_id =$row['Id']; 
         if ($row['Time'] > 200 )  
         { 
          $sql = 'KILL $process_id'; 
          mysql_query($sql); 
         } 
      }")
```

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference to your answer above but I am not dropping the database from within c#, i have updated the question above with this information

Comment: you delete the data? you have to close the connections?

Comment: No i drop the whole database, I think the issue in this case is the EF Context still believes the database exists.